# DB2 Java Spring @Transactional with Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW not reading Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, db2

I have a weird problem I can't figure out.
DB2 database
Java Spring 4
Hibernate 4

I have one transactional class:

```
public class B2BTrackingMsgProcessorImpl … {
  private GenericProcessor trackProcessor;

  @Transactional
  public void process(Message msg){ ….
      trackProcessor.process(msg);
   }
}

public class TrackingMsgProcessor …{
private ILookupUUIDXRef uuidXRefLookup;

   public void process(msg) {…
      uuidXRefLookup.getPayloadIdByUuid(uuid…);
   }

}


public interface ILookupUUIDXRef {
    PayloadIdXRef getPayloadIdByUuid(String uuid);
}

public class LookupUuidXrefImpl implements ILookupUUIDXRef {

    @Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
public PayloadIdXRef getPayloadIdByUuid(String uuid) {
}
```

So class "LookupUuidXrefImpl" creates a new transaction, and I want to read uncommitted.

Spring context:

```
<bean id="b2bTrackingMsgProcessor" class="B2BTrackingMsgProcessorImpl">
<property name="trackProcessor" ref="trackProcessor"/>
</bean>

<bean id="trackProcessor" class="TrackingMsgProcessor">
<property name="uuidXRefLookup" ref="uuidLookup"/>
</bean>

<bean id="uuidLookup" class="LookupUuidXrefImpl">
</bean>
```

The logs shows different transactions:

> DEBUG Tra
> ckingMsgProcessor - TransactionStatus = org.springframework.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionStatus@fc028b62

> DEBUG LookupUuidXrefImpl - TransactionStatus = org.springframework.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionStatus@a8aa0f45

However the select query does not have "with UR", and as far as the DBA checked, it's always CS isolation (default).

How can I make the new transaction read uncommitted "UR"
?

The SQL I see does not have "with ur":

`select a,b,c from PAYLOAD_ID_XREF payloadidx0_ where payloadidx0_.PAYLD_UUID=?`

even though the spring logs shows new transaction, UR:

`WebSphereUowTransactionManager  - Creating new transaction with name [null]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,ISOLATION_READ_UNCOMMITTED`

Comment: You're not seeing `WITH UR`, because the transaction manager does not handle transaction isolation on the statement level (in fact most RDBMSes don't even offer such a feature AFAIK). Instead, each ongoing transaction requires a separate connection, and isolation is set on the connection level.

Comment: Why would you need `WITH UR`? I've only seen this as a last resort, when performance is bad. It has drawbacks, though.

Comment: @ crizzis - that's a pain in the neck... I will not be able to create another connection with isolation UR.... unfortunately, but I will look into creating a native query where I would specify UR, see if that works.  @The Impaler - I have 6 concurrent threads spread over multiple JVM's all attempting to create a record of UUID, which creates collisions. I want to be able to reduce the number of collisions to the minimum, hence the UR. The 1st thread creating UUUID will succeed, all subsequent threads will just use the UUID already existent, and retry if transaction fails.